# Find signal number by signal name

Tags: linux, shell, sed, signals, aix

I want to trap signal `SIGTSTP`, as simple as this:

```
trap "" SIGTSTP
```

However, pure shell (`sh`) does not support signal name, so a trap must use the signal number instead, like this:

```
trap "" 20
```

Problem: signal numbers are  OS-dependent, so SIGTSTP in Linux is 20 but in AIX it's 18.

So to make it generic I decide to extract signal number from the result of `trap -l`. The raw input is:

```
 1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL
 5) SIGTRAP      6) SIGABRT      7) SIGEMT       8) SIGFPE
 9) SIGKILL     10) SIGBUS      11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGSYS
13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM     16) SIGURG
17) SIGSTOP     18) SIGTSTP     19) SIGCONT     20) SIGCHLD
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGIO       24) SIGXCPU
25) SIGXFSZ     27) SIGMSG      28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGPWR
30) SIGUSR1     31) SIGUSR2     32) SIGPROF     33) SIGDANGER
34) SIGVTALRM   35) SIGMIGRATE  36) SIGPRE      37) SIGVIRT
38) SIGALRM1    39) SIGWAITING  50) SIGRTMIN    51) SIGRTMIN+1
52) SIGRTMIN+2  53) SIGRTMIN+3  54) SIGRTMAX-3  55) SIGRTMAX-2
56) SIGRTMAX-1  57) SIGRTMAX    60) SIGKAP      61) SIGRETRACT
62) SIGSOUND    63) SIGSAK
```

I can't use `grep`, because the feature that I need, `--only-matching`, is not always supported. `trap -l | grep -oE "[0-9]+\) SIGTSTP" | cut -d')' -f1` works well, but only in Linux.

I also failed to use `sed` because of the greedy problem described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14776/why-isnt-sed-greedy-in-this-simple-case)

So `trap -l | sed -nr 's/.*([0-9]+)\) SIGTSTP.*/\1/p'` only returns `8`, not `18`

I want to make the extraction as generic as possible, so I won't assume `SIGTSTP` is a double-digit code, even when in reality it is.

Any suggestion?

Comment: POSIX trap supports 0, EXIT and signal symbolic names (without "SIG"); see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/trap.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try constraining the match with a word boundary:

`trap -l | sed -nr 's/.*\b([0-9]+)\) SIGTSTP.*/\1/p'`

This tested correctly [for me] for the target string as well as SIGPIPE.

Comment: AIX `sed` doesn't support `-r` - see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/sed.htm?cp=ssw_aix_53%2F1-2-0-18-22

Comment: @mklement0: hmmm that's odd -- the OP is using it in his question.

Comment: Good point. Still, I think a POSIX-features-only solutions is called for here.

Comment: @mklement0 the AIX I'm running on does support -r. However you have a point, if it is not POSIX compliant I need to be cautious.

Comment: @jstevenco Thanks buddy it works like a charm, at least my AIX and Linux.

Comment: Since using `-r` _is_ an option for the OP, this works well, but I suggest the following variation to avoid ambiguity (e.g., `SIGURS`, or to distinguish `SIGRTMAX-1` from `SIGRTMAX`): `trap -l | sed -nr 's/.*\b([0-9]+)\) SIGTSTP(\s.*|$)/\1/p'`
To make this work on BSD/OSX, you'd have to use `trap -l | sed -nE 's/.*[[:<:]]([0-9]+)\) SIGTSTP([[:blank:]].*|$)/\1/p'`.

Comment: @mklement0: nice additions for completeness

Comment: @mklement0  POSIX `-E` is available in newer versions of GNU sed, too. (at least version 4.7)

Answer (score 5):

To **get a signal's number by its name** in **`bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh`**, you can simply use:

```
kill -l TSTP # -> e.g., 18 - case doesn't matter, but do not use the "SIG" prefix
```

Since this uses the `kill` *builtin* (as opposed to the external-utility version, `/bin/kill`), this **should work on any platform where these shells are supported**.

---

Here's a **POSIX-compliant solution** that doesn't rely on a particular shell:

```
/bin/kill -l | tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' | 
  awk -v name='TSTP' 'toupper($0) == toupper(name) {print NR}' # don't use "SIG" prefix
```

- The *external* `kill` utility, `/bin/kill`, is used, with its `-l` option, for listing signals. While the [POSIX spec for `kill`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html) prescribes an output format, it doesn't mandate listing signals in a particular order. However, the order that makes sense is by their numerical value, and in practice that seems to be the case, and this approach relies on it.
- A caveat is that `/bin/kill` - unlike the `kill` builtins in bash, ksh, zsh, and dash - does NOT report the signals `SIGRTMIN` through `SIGRTMAX` on Linux.

---

As for the *inverse* operation - **getting a signal *name* by its *number*** - use `kill -l <number>`, e.g.:

```
 kill -l 18  # -> e.g., 'TSTP'
```

The `kill` builtins in `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, and `dash` all support this.

The external `/bin/kill` implementations vary with respect to the *syntax* of the above:

- macOS, GNU `kill`: the above form works.
- procps-ng `kill`, as present on Ubuntu in *18.04 or below*, for instance: only accepts
  `kill -l18` (or `kill --list=18`); that is, the option-argument must be *directly attached* to the `-l` option, which is the POSIX-compliant syntax, given that the signal number is an *optional* option-argument (`-l` by itself lists *all* signal names); see the [POSIX utility argument syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html).

Unfortunately, the other implementations listed above *only* support the - potentially ambiguous - `-l 18` form.

The procps-ng version that comes with *Ubuntu 19.10* (procps-ng 3.3.15) supports *both* forms (and also `--list 18`).<sup>Tip of the hat to [jarno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4414935/jarno) for his help.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
trap -l | sed  -nr 's/^([^0-9]*|.*[ \t])([0-9]+)\) SIGURG.*$/\2/p'
```

Now all runs correctly.

gaetano

Comment: Won't work for matches at the beginning of the line -- try it for SIGPIPE

Comment: As @jstevenco points out, this works only with double-digit signal codes and when the signal is not the beginning of line. What if SIGTSTP is say 8, not 18?

Comment: sorry for the mistake I corrected the command could you try and let me know  thanks

Comment: @jstevenco sorry again for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: I've found a [much simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29383998/45375). *This* answer may still be of interest to some with respect to differences between `sed` versions and writing portable `sed` commands.

---

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29378767/45375) works well under the following circumstances:

- a `sed` implementation that supports `-r` to enable support for *extended* regular expressions is available.
- `bash` is used to execute the command, as the `sed` command expects the output format that the *`bash`* `trap` *builtin* produces with the `-l` option.
- the platform's regex libraries support `\b` for word-boundary assertions.

This works for the OP, but not all platforms meet these requirements, notably BSD-like platforms, including OSX.

Caveat:

- The accepted solution only works unambiguously if you specify (a) a *full* signal name (e.g., `SIGUSR1` vs. just `SIGUSR`) that is (b) not also a substring of *another* signal name (e.g., `SIGRTMAX` vs. `SIGRTMAX-1`).

Given the capabilities of *extended* regexes, addressing this shortcoming wouldn't be hard on platforms with `sed -r` that support `\b` (this is an **amended version of the (non-portable) accepted solution**):

```
trap -l | sed -nr 's/.*\b([0-9]+)\) SIGTSTP(\s.*|$)/\1/p'
```

Note the *alternation* (`...|...`) at the end, which stipulates that the signal name be followed by either whitespace or the end of the line.
(Note that also using `\b` there would *not* work generically, because it would match before `-`, which *is* a valid part of some signal names).

Here's the **(also non-portable) equivalent of the amended accept answer for BSD-like platforms, including OSX**:

```
trap -l | sed -nE 's/.*[[:<:]]([0-9]+)\) SIGTSTP([[:blank:]].*|$)/\1/p'
```

Note that while `-E` also enables *extended* regular expressions, the particular flavor supported *differs* from the Linux one: `[[:<:]]` must be used instead of `\b`, and `[[:blank:]]` instead of `\s`.

Sadly, the limitations of [POSIX BREs (basic regular expressions)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) do not allow for alternations, and using `sed` portably restricts one to BREs.
Therefore, the ***extended* regex from the *amended* command cannot be directly emulated with a POSIX-compliant BRE**.
(Note that *GNU* `sed` *does* support alternation in BREs, but that's an non-compliant *extension*.)

Here's a **robust, portable solution** that **should work on any POSIX-compatible platform with `bash`**; it employs a workaround for not being able to use regex alternations:

```
trap -l |
 sed -n 's/^/ /; s/$/ /; s/.*[[:blank:]]\([0-9]\{1,\}\)) SIGTSTP[[:blank:]].*/\1/p'
```

- `s/^/ /; s/$/ /` simply prepends and appends a space character to each line, so that each signal number and signal name is guaranteed to be delimited by a space, which simplifies matching.
- Note that, due to having to use a *basic* regex, special chars. such as `(` and `{` require *escaping*.
- POSIX char. classes such as `[[:blank:]]` have to be used in lieu of shortcuts such as `\s`.
- Duplication symbol `+` has to be emulated with `\{1,\}`.

Note, however, that the solution is not POSIX-compliant per se:

- `trap` is a *builtin* in `bash`, so its `trap -l` output format is *the same* on *all* platforms that `bash` runs on - but do note that `bash` itself, while POSIX-*compatible*, is not mandated by POSIX itself and implements many *extensions* to the POSIX standard - `trap -l` being one of them.
  The above command relies on `bash`'s `trap -l` output format, as shown in the question.

---

**POSIX compatibility notes:**

- The [POSIX `trap` *builtin*](http://man.cx/trap) does NOT support `-l`, whereas the [POSIX `kill` *utility*](http://man.cx/kill) does, but it prescribes a *different format*:
  "When the `-l` option is specified, the symbolic name of each signal shall be written in the following format: `"%s%c", <signal_name>, <separator>`, where the `<signal_name>` is in uppercase, without the `SIG` prefix, and the `<separator>` shall be either a `<newline>` or a `<space>`. For the last signal written, `<separator>` shall be a `<newline>` - http://man.cx/kill;
  e.g.: `HUP INT QUIT ILL ...`
  The spec doesn't mandate the *order* in which signals should be listed, but in practice, implementations seem to list them in ascending order of numerical value.
- However, `bash` also has a `kill` *builtin*, whose `-l` option produces the *same* output as `trap -l`. Builtins take precedence over utilities, so `bash` `kill` builtin shadows the external `kill` utility. Thus, the output produced by `kill -l` (and `trap -l`) in `bash` deviates from the POSIX-mandated format as follows:

  - signal names are *prefixed with their numbers* in the form `<number>)`, followed by a space
  - signal names *do* have the `SIG` name prefix.
- Thus, `bash`'s `kill -l` output is actively NON-POSIX compliant, UNLESS you run `bash` in POSIX mode (e.g., by running `shopt -so posix`). By contrast, the `kill` builtins in `ksh`, `zsh`, and `dash` DO conform to the POSIX-mandated output format *by default*.

Comment: :D I didn't know `kill -l` produces the same result as `trap -l`. Thanks for the effort. If my question is for a POSIX-compliant solution I'll definitely pick your answer.